# Whre can I find the 'envirnoment id' and 'collection id' on the Watson Discvoery tool?

Tags: testing, credentials, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I am trying to do some tests with IBM Watson Discovery but I need som info as the 'envirnoment ID' and the 'collection ID', but I can't find it anywhere.

Does anyone now?

Thank you

I have tried through the IBM ckoud dashboard where I can only find the API Key and URL, but nothung else. ON the actual tool itself I am not having an success either.